# Want to extract all inner text and link from td's content

Tags: jquery, html

here is my sample td's content.

```
<table id='test' border=1><tr><td>hello....</td></tr>
<tfoot>
<tr class="webgrid-footer">
    <td colspan="6">1 
        <a href="Show3.html" >2</a> 
        <a href="Show3.html" >3</a> 
        <a href="Show3.html" >4</a> 
        <a href="Show3.html" >&gt;</a> 
        <a href="Show3.html" >&gt;&gt;</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

my objective is to extract inner text from html element....like `1 or 2 or &gt; or &gt;&gt;`

this script i am using to get inner text...i am bit close but still not giving right result. so please anyone has a look and give me rectified code.

```
function getOuterHtml($el){
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.appendChild($el[0].cloneNode(true));
    return wrapper.innerHTML;
} 

var $elements = $('.webgrid-footer td').contents()
.filter(function() 
{
  return (this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== '')
         || this.nodeType === 1;
});  

var $div = $('<div id="content" />');
var $list = $('<ul />');
var strData='';

$elements.each(function(){
    if($(this).html()===null)
    {
        alert(getOuterHtml($(this)));
    }
    else
    {
        alert(getOuterHtml($(this)));
    }
    var $item = $('<li />').append($(this));      
    $list.append($item);
});
$div.append($list);
//alert(strData);
$('#dv').append($div);
```

here is js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/ab69osqu/

looking for suggestion. thanks

Comment: "*[I] am...close but still not [getting] right result...*" - what is the expected "*right*" result? Where does your code fail, and in what way? What do you want to do with the retrieved text? Hold it in an array? Wrap it in other elements and append to the page? Where in the page?

Comment: can u plzz come with sample code for what u said.

Comment: No, not until you take the time to ask a question with sufficient detail that would allow me to offer a sensible, and useful, answer. I'd strongly suggest reading the "[ask]" guidelines.

Comment: update posted code. by this function `getOuterHtml()` now i am getting inner element but still i am not getting inner text like `1..2..& &gt;` any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the following

```
$(this).text();
```

instead of just doing

```
$(this);
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ab69osqu/1/) I believe this is what you are looking for